# .NET CORE AJAX post datos null en mi controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Estoy tratando de enviar algunos datos a mi controlador a través de ajax, pero al ejecutarlo envía los datos vacíos, no encuentro la manera de resolverlo.

Este es mi código con el que envío los datos del Nombre a mi controlador Guardar()

```js
function Guardar() {
    var $data = {
        oClientes: {
            Nombres: "23",
        }
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Guardar", "Clientes")",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify($data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.resultado) {
                tabla_persona.ajax.reload();
                $('#FormModal').modal('hide');
            } else {
                alert("No se pudo guardar los cambios");
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        },
        beforeSend: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

Ahora con el siguiente controlador se supone que debo recopilar los datos de Nombres

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Guardar(ClientesModel oPersona)
{
    var respuesta = true;
    var id = oPersona.IdCliente;
    var pers = oPersona.Nombres;

    return Json(new { data = respuesta });
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo no llena el campo de nombre, solo queda null

En esta imagen se puede ver que no me da nada

[image: En esta imagen se puede ver que no me da nada]

En la variable de datos del script si hay datos

[image: En la variable de datos del script si hay datos]

Comment: El controlador en el que se encuentra tu metodo es un apicontroller o un controlador de mvc?

Comment: intenta hacer el ajax sin el dataType , ni el contentType y el data: $data , sin el stringify()

Comment: Me late que andas iniciando con el framework, revisa este video, te será de ayuda para ver el panorama: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pude resolverlo la solución fue agregar lo siguiente en mi controller:

```
[HttpPost("~/Clientes/Guardar")]
        public JsonResult Guardar([FromBody] ClientesModel oClientes)
        {
            var respuesta = true;

            respuesta = _ClientesDatos.Guardar(oClientes);

            //var id = oClientes.IdCliente;
            //var pers = oClientes.Nombres;
           
            return Json(new { data = respuesta });
        }
```

también tuve que quitar de mi js lo siguiente:

antes:

```
   var $data = {
                oClientes: {
                    Nombres: "23",
                }
            }
```

ahora :

```
   var $data = {
               
                    Nombres: "23",
              
            }
```

quité oclientes de mi variable $data.

Comment: Realmente no tenías que cambiar el controlador, lo que sucede es que el controlador esperaba un objeto del tipo: "ClientesModel", tu le enviabas un string.

Comment: si es verdad , gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver quitando el

```
 dataType, contentType y el JSON.stringify
```

como indicó @Stial Manstike